# How can I take control of the rendering of a file entity when inlined in text?

Tags: media, entities, files

There are excellent instructions for how to allow embedding [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) into text fields here [Setting up WYSIWYG and CKEditor to include Media Browser / Embed Media button](http://drupal.org/node/1882314).

Now I'm trying to control the output of that embedding process, specifically I'm trying to render a text field for a caption next to an image. I started out by adding a new view mode to the file entity with [hook_entity_info_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7), configured this View mode to display the correct fields, and thought that would output as expected.

However, this by itself does nothing unless "File display" settings are also added, and I can't seem to figure out how to make them respect field settings. I've done a fair amount of debugging and hacking by now, and can't get this right. I could fill the question with a great deal of more details, but given that I can't make heads or tails out of the problem, it's unlikely to be very useful.

The question [How do I control the file appearance using File Entity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18815/how-do-i-control-the-file-appearance-using-file-entity) is definitely related, and possibly even a duplicate, but as this one concerns specifically inline media, it may be different enough that open this separate question.

Comment: Related (but different) question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19706/image-insert-and-theming

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is http://drupal.org/sandbox/DevinCarlson/1823634 - which is an add on to media, but I'm not certain whether or not it can also display fields that are attached to a file entity.

As per http://drupal.org/node/1792738 this functionality is planned to be rolled into the media module at some stage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible yet.  See http://drupal.org/node/1421786 and http://drupal.org/node/1792738

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this quite a bit (sometimes with varying degrees of success). Which version of Media are you using? [7.x-2.0-alpha3](https://www.drupal.org/node/2120855) includes Media WYSIWYG View Mode as a submodule, which allows you to select a view mode when inserting media into the WYSIWYG - so you can control the display however you like. For example, I have a view mode that includes caption fields, and I can select that when inserting an image.

I know it's only alpha, but many people have been using 2.x for a very long time - I've had it in production for over two years now, with no problems directly attributable to its not being an official release.